# Tools and strategies for tracking index changes with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, version-control

I have starting working with MongoDB on a new project and have found it to be an excellent match for what we are trying to do.

There are numerous developers on the project and all of them will be adding new collections and indexes to the database. Each developer is responsible for setting up and connecting to a MongoDB server on their local machine.

One thing I would like to set up is a system for managing MongoDB index changes in source control, similar to the way database migrations works in RoR. This would allow a developer who created a new collection to also include the proper indexes for that collection when committing their changes to source control. I figured something like this would have already been done, but I was surprised to find very little on the subject.

Are their any tools or tried and true strategies for tracking MongoDB index changes in source control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create/update indices using one of the drivers (java, python, ruby, ...) or mongodb shell and javascript code effectively, both of which can be easily kept version controlled and close to the code. That might be the reason you haven't found much on the topic, because it's quite strait-forward. Or maybe the field is new (2 years or so vs 40+ years for RDBMs) :)

Comment: Having your `ensureIndex` commands be a part of the application initialization code seems like a good practice. See Scott Hernandez's email here: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/fc7762cd51f350be

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer since you are the only one who responded and I ended up doing exactly as you suggested. Wasn't too hard. I used a combination of psake, shell scripts, and the mongo --eval command line switch.